# Prevent a subclass from overriding interface

Tags: java

Is there a way to prevent a subclass from overriding the implementation of 
interface that super class implement.

I want to create a custom view contains a `listView` in android and implement `onScroll` listener but when the subclass set `onScroll` listener on the list. the listener at the super class is never invoked.

Comment: `final` keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, there is.**

The final word on that is: `final`

By declaring a method `final` you state that subclasses are not allowed to `@Override` this method (even without annotation that is).

Consider this interface:

```
interface MyInter  {
   public void foo();

   public String bar();
}
```

And your class

```
public class MyClass implements MyInter {

  @Override 
  public final void foo() {
    //Cant touch this
  }

  @Override
  public String bar() {
    return "foo";
  }

}
```

Now your third class is allowed to extend MyClass - but limited to overriding `bar()` because `foo()` is protected by `final` keyword:

```
public class Thirs extends MyClass {
   @Override
   public String bar() {
     return "bar";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `final` keyword to do so.

E.g:

```
public final void foo() {
    ....
}
```